# Current time always outputs as 00 in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

For some reason, if I have a file like so:

```py
import datetime
print(datetime.date.today().strftime("%H %M %S"))
```

The output is always:

```
00 00 00
```

I'm running Python 3.7.4 on Windows, can anyone help?

Comment: you invoke today() and not now(), which makes date throw away time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `today` gives you the *day,* not the time. Hence it probably just gives you midnight at the start of the day.

If you want the *time,* use this code:

```
>>> print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H %M %S"))
14 12 38
```